# PHP5 - pgsql Module not loaded

Tags: postgresql, apache2, php-pgsql

I am trying to get work PostgresSQL with PHP, but i stuck on that apache error:
`Call to undefined function pg_connect()`.

When i run `phpinfo()` i cannot see that my module is loaded, but i do not know why. The `pgsql.ini` files were loaded. And when i open them, i can see, that the extension is enabled `extension=pgsql.so`. Under `/usr/lib64/php5/extensions` there is the .so file. Even the permission are same like the other modules.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could describe what operating system you are using. I'm assume Linux, but which distribution? One package that is often forgotten when installing postgresql and php is php5-pgsql. This is the connection between the two. For some reason I cannot explain, it is best if all three are installed together. So I suggest uninstalling postgresql and php and then installing postgresql, php5 and php5-pgsql. I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. Some libraries where not found.
1.) First of all run `php -version`
2.) If there is an error where it described that some libraries are missing, you can solve it like me
3.) Search for the files on your system `find / -name {LIBRARY NAME}`
3a.) If you found them, just create a symlink to `/usr/lib64`
3b.) If not, find a way to get them and 3 **3a**